# Can we use a makruh for pleasure without getting sinful?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, makruh

As Salam o Alikum brothers and sisters in faith. I have been suffering from a medical condition for 6 years now. When it first started, I had to visit so many medical experts but their prescriptions failed to give the required results.

After 3 years of serious medication, I had to move on to something new that could  calm my nerves. That thing was THC, particularly obtained from hash. It has been proven to be a good source of relief (All praise to Allah).

Now I don't need it often because I feel better. So if I keep using Hash rather for the recreational purpose, would it be Legal in Islamic shariah or not?

Answer (score 2):

There's hardly any commandment that has more rational evidence than the one not to take drugs.

The evidence is that we can become addicted to it and get delivered to the evil.

The fact that you want to continue consuming the drug without a medical use is a clear sign of this danger. So follow God's advice and refrain from using it.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont need it anymore, then i would say 100% dont use it, it is a drug and it is haram in islam if not for the right reasons. and it will only do you harm now, so you should stay away from it and pray to Allah to help you to not do it.

Answer (score -1):

Don’t do the drugs, Bro. There are way better recreations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/62658)